# next js error when hard refresh page with dynamic query parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

i have a next js app with dynamic page parameter, when i hard reload it in  development mood it works fine , but in production i get this error 404 - File or directory not found.
here is the code i use:

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import NewsDetails from "../../../Components/news/newsDetails";
import HeadPage from "../../HeadPage";
import { GeneralLoading } from "../../../Components/ui/LoadingScreens";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const Details = () => {
  const [id, setID] = useState(null);
  const router = useRouter();

  // // fire when router.query is updated
  useEffect(() => {
    const { id } = router.query
    console.log(id);
    setID(id);
  }, [router.query?.id]);

  // const id = router.query['id'];
  // if (!id) return null
  // if(id) {
  //   return (
  //     id && <>
  //         <HeadPage />
  //         <h1>test</h1>
  //         <NewsDetails params={id} />
  //      </>
  //   )
  // } else {
  //   return <h1>Test else</h1>
  // }
  
  
   if (!id) {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          {" "}
          <GeneralLoading />{" "}
        </div>
      </>
    );
   } else {
    return (
      <>
        <HeadPage />
        <NewsDetails params={id} />
      </>
    );
   }
};

export default Details;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

i also tried to add this to the end of prev code , but i coudn't build and export the app then with this function inside it

```js
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const { id } = context.query;
  // If id is "undefined", since "undefined" cannot be serialized, server will throw error
  // But null can be serializable
  if (!id) {
    id = null;
  }
  // now we are passing the id to the component
  return { props: { id:id } };
}
```

then i tried to change it to this function but  also didn't work

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { id } = context.query;
  // If id is "undefined", since "undefined" cannot be serialized, server will throw error
  // But null can be serializable
  if (!id) {
    id = null;
  }
  // now we are passing the id to the component
  return { props: { id:id } };
};
```

Comment: The problem here is that nextjs changes the browser's location history, so once you navigate to website.com/users/1 or something, a hard refresh will try and open that location directly from the server. Which causes a 404 error. The solution is to use for instance a .htaccess file (depends on your server) to redirect all requests that aren't files to /index.html

Comment: @ChrisG what can id with the server to avoid this problem, please.

Comment: What kind of server do you have? Is it apache? (also, I just told you *exactly* what you have to do, why answer like that? this is not a "let a pro solve your basic issue for free" website) Also, here's a great website I found [click](https://www.google.com/search?q=nextjs+refresh+404)

Comment: @ChrisG i use IIS server

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51755370/react-router-iis-how-to-enable-routing

Comment: thank you, this solution works fine with react apps and i tried it before,
but its not for next js apps

Comment: Basic static hosting has [limitations](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features). However you can use [issnode](https://github.com/Azure/iisnode) instead to actually run the app on your ISS server. This should take care of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

when you have dynamic params you should use `getStaticPaths` function
NextJs wants know what exactly are this dynamic params.

use `getStaticPaths` like this.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { id: 1 } }, 
      { params: { id: 2 } }, 
       ...
    ],
    fallback: true, false or "blocking" 
  };
}
```

you must tell NextJs that what is your id(s)
if you have to many ids set fallback to true
so NextJs doesn't generate your file before page render.

see this link for more info
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths

Comment: i tried this solution, when i try to export i get this error "Pages with `fallback` enabled in `getStaticPaths` can not be exported"

Comment: also i am using pagination in the component, so i fetch only 10 records per page how can i make paths dynamic

Comment: If you have fallback as true means this page is a dynamic page (user/[id].js) and you DON'T want to pre-render all the pages because you have many data to pre-render.